# View in landscape appears as portrait

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a application that run in landscape mode only...it works great, but I did create another view in my application and his xib is "landscape", didn't use autolayout and did implement shouldAutoRotate in my controller..but when I enter on this view, the view is completely different from xib

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

The xib's print
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/3t2b.png/

The ipad's print
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/196/nqku.png/

Answer (score 1):

In info plist check values of

Supported interface orientations

Keep only these two items

1. Landscape (left home button)
2. Landscape (right home button)

Comment: I did check and are only these two itens

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem using:

```
[self presentViewController:_inAppPurchaseView animated:FALSE completion:nil];
```

instead of:

```
  [self.window addSubView:_inAppPurchase.view];
```